# Конвертер TIFF в CDR

Tags: corel-draw

Надо конвертировать TIFF файл в CDR (попросили cdr в типографии), я пытался онлайн конвертеры, но они фейлят конвертация, и как я понял это невозможно (но это нигде не написано)
скажите пожалуйста как можно сконвертировать в cdr (может через coraldraw или сконвертировать сначала в одно расширение, потом уже в cdr)
любой совет будет much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямой конвертации растра в вектор нет. У Corel Draw есть встроенный инструмент для преобразования в вектор. В старых версиях (8, 9, 10) это было отдельное приложение - Corel Trace, в новых (в 15-ой точно) этот функционал уже встроен.
В зависимости от детализации и разрешения вашего TIF-растра получится конфетка или не конфетка.

Но есть и альтернативный вариант - просто засунуть ваш растровый TIF в CDR-файл и смасштабировать как надо. Лично сам так делал - вставлял в корел разные картинки, в т.ч. и JPG, чтобы при печати получить точный размер объектов. Иногда при вставке картинки может возникнуть ошибка (редко) - что-то с форматом. В этом случае я открывал это изображение каким-нибудь графическим редактором (растровым) и пересохранял (иногда меняя цветовую схему и/или формат). Также можно "напечатать" ваш TIF с помощью какого-нибудь виртуального PDF-принтера (обязательно установить в настройках печати максимальное качество!), и потом уже эту PDF'ку кидать в корел.

В результате:
Этот CDR-файл с картинкой внутри отправите в типографию.

Какой вариант более правильный в каждом подобном случае можно сказать только после просмотра оригинального TIF-файла.

Comment: Спасибо большое, скачал CorelDraw, запихнул туда картинку и смаштабировал, сохранил как проект .cdr и все получилось :)

Comment: Типография приняла такое? :)

Comment: Это надо было тренеру подмочь с вопросом, я ему скинул, а дальше не знаю как там) А почему бы не приняла? Качество сильно режется?

Comment: Смотря какое качество исходной картинки и какой размер будет на выходе из типографии. Если разрешение изображения низкое, и его нужно растянуть, чтобы напечатать на формате А1, например, или вообще - сделать баннер, то скорее всего придется делать трассировку и переводить все в вектор.

Comment: Там надо распечатать изображение на перчатках (боксерских), так что не думаю,что там будет что-то критичное)